# OpenCMS 8.5 Eclipse Integration

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, opencms

I am a Java Developer and want to know how could I use OpenCMS with Eclipse, there has a [wiki](http://www.opencms-wiki.org/wiki/Eclipse_integration) page about it but web links has been broken there. I also searched over internet but most all posts related to OpenCms 7.0 But I am using OpenCMS 8.5 its structure is totally different. There also has a book but again its only for OpenCMS 7.0. I need help to configure OpenCMS 8.5 with Eclipse.

Thanks

Comment: You can try the module manager on http://johnen.biz/en/blog/OpenCms-Module-Manager/

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't  matter the version of opencms you can access with webdav, I use the version 9.0.1 and eclipse kepler, work perfectly with WebDav.

 in your eclipse, dowload and install webdav http://update.eclipse.org/updates/3.3

also you should check if the webdav is configured http://www.opencms-wiki.org/wiki/WebDAV_access_to_the_OpenCms_VFS

Or you can acces with CMIS check de **documentation v8.5.2 seccion 13 CMIS**

Books OpenCms 7 Development: Extending and customizing OpenCms through its Java Api 

Reference
[eclipse-galileo-webdav-plugin-opencms](http://heiflo.com/2009/07/eclipse-galileo-webdav-plugin/)